# Split and Objects - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function called `"countStr"`.

I need to return an object where each key is a word in the given string, with its value being how many times that word appeared in the given  string. If the string is empty it must return an empty object.

Here's my function so far:

```
function countStr(str) {
   myObject = {};
  if(str.length === 0) {
    return myObject;
  } else {
    myArray = str.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray; i++) {
      var key = myArray[i];
      if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        myObject[key]++;
      } else {
        myObject[key];
      }
    }
    return myObject;
  }
}

var output = countStr('ask me lots get me lots'); 
console.log(output); // --> IT MUST OUTPUT {ask: 1, me: 2, lots: 2, get: 1}
```

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: just missing length for `myArray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are small issues with your code.

1. You need to iterate from zero to the `length` of the array.
2. You need to initialize the object items with 1 in the `else` case.
3. You should use local variables with the `var` to avoid polluting your top level namespace.

Here is the fixed version:

```
function countStr(str) {
  var myObject = {};
  if(str.length === 0) {
    return myObject;
  } else {
    var myArray = str.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      var key = myArray[i];
      if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        myObject[key]++;
      } else {
        myObject[key] = 1;
      }
    }
    return myObject;
  }
}

var output = countStr('ask me lots get me lots');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Also, you should decalre ```myObject``` using ```var```

Comment: I just added that. :) BTW the `myArray` declaration was also wrong.

Comment: `var` is not necessary

Comment: Not necessary if you want to pollute your namespace that is why I wrote should.

Comment: @Weedoze: Not necessary to run, but it is bad code to leak your local variables to the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce()` like this

```js
function countStr(str) {
  return str.trim().length ? str.split(' ').reduce((o,s)=>{
    o[s] = o[s] || 0;
    o[s]++;
    return o;
  }, {}) : {};
}

var output = countStr('ask me lots get me lots');
console.log(output); // --> {ask: 1, me: 2, lots: 2, get: 1}
```

Other wise in your code, you were missing `Array.length` in your `for` condition and the `else` should be like `myObject[key]=1`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countStr(str) {
   myObject = {};
   var myArray = [];
  if(str.length === 0) {

    return myObject;
  } else {
   myArray = str.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      var key = myArray[i];
      if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     myObject[key]++;     
      } else {     
      myObject[key]=1;
      }
    }
    return myObject;
  }
}

var output = countStr('ask me lots get me lots'); 
console.log(output);
```